# Retrofit 2 POST XML and get JSON answer from API. with Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, simple-framework

I need to send XML to server and I want server sends me back JSON.
I'am using Retrofit 2 + Kotlin

1. Retrofit2 method(in methods interface):

   ```
   @Headers("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=urf-8",
           "Accept: application/json")
   @POST(Connectors.SECRET_LINK)
   fun sendCustomXml(@Body data: XmlHolder): Observable<String>
   ```
2. Retrofit2 service:

   ```
   private fun <S> createService(serviceClass: Class<S>): S {
       val retrofit = 
       return 
   }

   init {
       initLoggingInterceptor()

       val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()) //here it is I thought
               .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())

       mService = builder.client(getHttpClient()).build().create(ApiMethods::class.java))
   }
   ```
3. XML object I need to send like XML(tags and so on):

   ```
   @Root(name = "root_element")
   class XmlHolder {

       @Attribute(name = "xmlns")
       private val mXmlns = "http://www.anr.ru/types"

       @Attribute(name = "type")
       private val mType = "request"

       @Element(name = "data")
       private val mData = Data()

       inner class Data {

           @Attribute(name = "code")
           private val mCode = "P0116"

           @Element(name = "list_model")
           private val mListModel = "123"
       }
   }
   ```

for now I got 400 error from server. shit.

Jake Wharton, can you suggest any solutions to me? :)
Any help, any examples, please, people...

Comment: and one more thing: i send it, and loggingInterceptor writing this to log:
--> POST https://<myUrl i hide it> http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/xml
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2801
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json

and it prints my request data like json, not like xml with tags .....

Comment: "urf-8" is not a valid charset. Try replacing with "utf-8".

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/JsonAndXmlConverters.java This may help you.

Comment: yole, I just wrote here with mistake. charset is not the problem (